Best way to remove repeated data in JavaScript array
Suppose you have a list like this:
[1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2]

What's the most efficient way to remove repeated data (not duplicates) so no element appears after itself? For this example, the result should be:
[1, 2, 1, 2]

For example, this could be solved with filter or a for loop remembering the last element. But is there something more elegant? Or which option is most efficient?
for loop:
const arr = [1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2];
const result = [arr[0]];
let lastElement = arr[0];
for (let i = 1, n = arr.length; i < n; ++i) {
  if (arr[i] !== lastElement) {
    lastElement = arr[i];
    result.push(lastElement);
  }
}

filter:
const result = [1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2].filter((element, index, arr) => element !== arr[index - 1]);


what is actually your way?

Not sure I get why this id downvoted ... there are a few options to do this, this is not about duplicated and the problem exist in practice. Happy to delete the question if this is received so negatively.

i didn't dv, but an attempt is necessary. what goes wrong?

Have been using this for a long time, never knew an attempt is necessary. I can add a solution I have written here, but I was mostly interested and how other people would solve this. I feel an attempt kinda biases answers, but I can provide one. However, I think maybe I just better delete the question. Answers to question like "what is the best way to remove duplicated" helped me the most, so I thought this is interesting.

Have a go at jsperf and see for yourself  - otherwise it will be an opinion you are requesting and that is against the SO guidelines

@mplungjan: I don’t think the question of the best way to do things in programming always fits into the “opinion-based” category. There are lots of objective advantages that can’t always be anticipated ahead of time.

btw, why not start with index 1?  for non empty arrays, the value at index zero is always unique.

@NinaScholz His code is so far the fastest. Can you make a faster one? https://jsperf.app/popose/2

Just filter with comparing with the previous item:


const result = [1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2].filter((item, idx, arr) => !idx || item !== arr[idx - 1]);
console.log(result);



If you want it fast with bigger number of items, you could pre-allocate the result array:


const data = [1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2];

  const result = Array(data.length);
  let j = 1;
  let lastElement = result[0] = data[0];
  for (let i = 1, n = data.length; i < n; ++i) {
    if (data[i] !== lastElement) {
      result[j++] = lastElement = data[i];
    }
  }
  result.length = j;
  console.log(result);



And a benchmark:
` Chrome/123
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
>                                 n=8        |      n=80       |       n=800        |       n=8000      
Alexander for+preallocate     1.23x x10m 311 | ■ 1.00x x1m 125 | ■ 1.00x   x1m 1004 | ■ 1.00x x100k 1035
Thorben Croisé (OP)         ■ 1.00x x10m 253 | ■ 1.00x x1m 125 |   1.62x x100k  163 |   1.37x  x10k  142
mplungjan for loop            1.19x x10m 302 |   1.36x x1m 170 |   1.88x x100k  189 |   1.86x  x10k  192
Alexander                     1.01x x10m 255 |   1.18x x1m 147 |   2.12x x100k  213 |   2.69x  x10k  278
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
https://github.com/silentmantra/benchmark `



const $chunk = [1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2];
const $input = [];
const data = $input;

// @benchmark mplungjan for loop
const removeRepeated = (data) => {
  const result = [];
  for (let i = 0, len = data.length; i < len; i++) {
    if (i === 0 || data[i] !== data[i - 1]) {
      result.push(data[i]);
    }
  }
  return result;
};

removeRepeated(data);

// @benchmark Alexander
data.filter((item, idx, arr) => !idx || item !== arr[idx - 1]);

// @benchmark Alexander for+preallocate
{
  const result = Array(data.length);
  let j = 1;
  let lastElement = result[0] = data[0];
  for (let i = 1, n = data.length; i < n; ++i) {
    if (data[i] !== lastElement) {
      result[j++] = lastElement = data[i];
    }
  }
  result.length = j;
  result;
}

// @benchmark Thorben Croisé (OP)
{
  const result = [data[0]];
  let lastElement = data[0];
  for (let i = 1, n = data.length; i < n; ++i) {
    if (data[i] !== lastElement) {
      lastElement = data[i];
      result.push(lastElement);
    }
  }
  result;
}

/*@skip*/ fetch('https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/silentmantra/benchmark/loader.js').then(r => r.text().then(eval));




Please try with 10000 elements too

@mplungjan i guess the difference between 10000 and 8000 would be minimal, it's not an order magnitude

Sorry, I did not notice. I only saw [1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2] So 8000 is 8000 times or elements?

@mplungjan nope, it's total item count, it's controlled by const $chunks = [1, 10, 100, 1000] (default, so not declared), if you add 10000 to $chunks, the last benchmark will be 80000 items. it's described in the docs. the element count is a number of chunks * $chunk.length

So green squares are best?

@mplungjan yes, the best, the overall best solution is considered with the most number of items (the last column, sorted first)

Could you add trincot's inplace example?

@mplungjan trincots inplace needs special treatment. i support $clone() function to clone data before a cycle, but not sure whether it works with both inplace and pure benchmarks. it's a difficult case (mix the both approaches). otherwise it doesn't make sense to run next cycles on already mutated array

You put my name on the wrong code

@mplungjan lol, then the OP won the battle)

Yep. It does seem so - and trincot overall

@mplungjan i've pre-allocated the result, it's even faster))

Your code seems quite optimal. Just one remark: it will fail for an empty array as input, so I would suggest adding a guard for that.
If it is acceptable to perform the action inplace, mutating the input array instead of creating a new one, you can still get some time gain:
function removeRepetitionsInplace(arr) {
    if (arr.length < 2) return;
    let k = 0;
    let lastElement = arr[0];
    for (let i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] !== lastElement) {
            lastElement = arr[++k] = arr[i];
        }
    }
    arr.length = k + 1;
}

See performance tests at https://jsperf.app/popose/3 (added test case to mplungjan's)


And if you change for (let i=1, n=data.length; i<n;i++) you save a calculation https://jsperf.app/popose/4

mplugjan, I believe this type of optimisation is already performed by JS engines, so there is not really a repeated calculation. See For-loop performance: storing array length in a variable

Well, SOME of the perfs in that question seem to agree with me  https://jsben.ch/y3SpC

Also I am PRETTY sure it will be a larger difference if looping over a DOM collection

Yes, I am PRETTY sure about that as well, certainly when it is a live collection. But we're discussing arrays here.

I use it when I remember. It costs nothing and is defensive enough for me to use.

Reduce and filter are normally slower for large arrays than for loops
JSPerf on mine, Alexander's, Trinco't and OP's code: https://jsperf.app/popose/5
Your for loop is faster than mine (but not by much)
10000 elements



const removeRepeated = (data) => {
  const result = [];
  for (let i = 0, len = data.length; i < len; i++) {
    if (i === 0 || data[i] !== data[i - 1]) {
      result.push(data[i]);
    }
  }
  return result;
};

// Example usage
const data = [1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2];
const result = removeRepeated(data);
console.log(result); // Expected output: [1, 2, 1, 2]




i was wrong about jsperf, since you benchmarked with 10000 items, seems the same results, but i prefer my benchmark since i can inject it here)
